# How to send param to mui/index/renderer in listing grid

Tags: admin, grid

I'm building an admin grid, i'm sending a parameter to the controller, but when de datasource updates grid via ajax on mui/index/renderer, this url parameter is losing, how can i send this parameter to mui/index/renderer.

this is the datasource.

> 

```
    <settings>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
        </storageConfig>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render">
            <param name="indexField">entity_id</param>
        </updateUrl>
    </settings>
    <aclResource>Magento_Customer::online</aclResource>
    <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="customerdocs_wholesaler_documents_list_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
```

Comment: Its a good question, I would like to see the answer to this one. I was struggling with this some weeks ago. I had an listing component with tab component to the left. When using the tab to the left Magento was requesting the listing using ajax with mui/index/renderer. I tried different variants of export and import in the ui component but never managed to solve it, I ended up using the magento session cookie....

Answer (score 0):

You can inspire from this tutorial to change how the url is generated: https://cedcommerce.com/blog/magento-2-ui-grid-filter-collection-according-to-the-custom-parameter-available-in-the-url/